# How can I redirect all URL versions to https in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now I get 2 redirects if someone lands on http://www - In that case, the redirect chain is:

http://www to https://www to https://

It should be only:

http://www to https://

I believe the problem lies somewhere in the first 3 rows of my .htaccess which is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Prevent trailing slash on files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.(html|php|xml|css|xsl)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you really have the host name part of the substitution hard-coded as `example.com`, that rather can‘t be the case … First of all make sure this isn’t your browser cache fooling you, some browsers cache redirects real heavily.

Comment: I see the double redirect when I check with online redirect checkers, e.g., https://httpstatus.io/